# How to make SpriteView display physics or node count

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, sprite-kit, spriteview

When I try to set the `showPhysics` property to `true` in the `didMove(to:)` function of my Scene it doesn't do anything when I present it using a SpriteView in SwiftUI. The same thing happens when I try to show the FPS and node count. Here is the code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        view.showsFPS = true
        size = view.frame.size
        
        addChild(SKSpriteNode(color: .yellow, size: CGSizeMake(50, 50)))
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("My Game")
            SpriteView(scene: GameScene())
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Is this a bug or am I using SpriteView wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to set these using the [SpriteView.DebugOptions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/spriteview/debugoptions) when you create your `SpriteView`.

For example:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("My Game")
            SpriteView(scene: GameScene(), debugOptions: [.showsFPS, .showsNodeCount, .showsPhysics])
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```